# TF400324 error, but only when using the TFS API

Tags: c#, tfs

I've seen a lot of discussion about "TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server", but everything I've read relates to DNS or proxies, and reflect being unable to connect to TFS at all, through any channel.  My case is different: I cannot reach my TFS server when using the .NET library, but it works fine using Visual Studio's workflow tools, and I can reach the same URL just fine in a browser.

Zee code, it is here:

```
private TfsConfigurationServer  _server;
...
Uri  url    = new Uri(serverName + rootFolder);
var  creds1 = new NetworkCredential(username, password, Environment.UserDomainName);
var  creds2 = new BasicAuthCredential(creds1);
var  creds3 = new TfsClientCredentials(creds2)  { AllowInteractive = false };
_server = new TfsConfigurationServer(url, creds3);

// Throws Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException
_server.Authenticate();
```

The creds are needlessly elaborate because I've tried various suggested solutions, but I don't think that's relevant; I get the same behavior with any other creds I've tried, or no creds at all.

If I copy the exact URL to a browser, I can authenticate and proceed.  Within Visual Studio I can connect to TFS using Source Control Explorer and other tools, without explicitly authenticating.  What might the library want handled differently?

Additional detail from the error:

```
Team Foundation services are not available from server https://tfs.imahufflepuff.com:8080/tfs/Root/Project.
Technical information (for administrator):
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
  ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

We don't have an in-house TFS admin, otherwise I'd kick this issue over to him.  I've tried to use Fiddler to get additional detail, but VS consistently refuses to show up there.  I can reach an externally-hosted API while debugging, so I don't think there's a network or proxy problem locking down VS.

Comment: Are you using the same Client API version and Server version. e.g. 11.0 DLL's for TFS 2012, 12.0 DLL's for TFS 2013. Just looking at the URI, is that correct, it should be: `http://mytfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection` no more, no less.

Comment: The server was recently upgraded to 2013, while I'm on 2012 (v11 libraries), but the problem occurred before this and has persisted after.

Comment: Does fiddler show anything interesting?

Comment: Unfortunately Visual Studio does not show up in Fiddler when using these TFS classes, though it does for (e.g.) AtTask's cloud-hosted API.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `TfsTeamProjectCollection` class instead of `TfsConfigurationServer` ?
E.g.

```
Uri url = new Uri(serverName + rootFolder);
var creds = new NetworkCredential(username, password, Environment.UserDomainName);
var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(url, creds);
server.Authenticate();
```

---

You can also try debugging this issue using Fiddler. You'll have to change VS proxy settings before starting Fiddler:

- Either set the registry key `reg add hkcu\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\RequestSettings
  /v BypassProxyOnLocal /t REG_SZ /d False`

or

- Set environment variable TFS_BYPASS_PROXY_ON_LOCAL=0

Comment: I get the same error messages with `TfsTeamProjectCollection`.  Though since you've brought it up, if you can clarify the differences between the two, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: My understanding is that TfsConfigurationServer is a legacy class which existed before TFS 2010 when the notion of Team Project Collection was introduced. I believe that you should always use TfsTeamProjectCollection which is newer. You can find more details about it in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/12/07/tfs2010-object-model-api-changes-after-beta-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an SSL handshake issue at its root, which has nothing to do with the TFS and HTTP protocol and authentication, they sit above SSL. So make sure you have a valid certificate, matching hostname, good validity, accessible CRL where the cert is not revoked, etc. Also check in other browsers or openssl.exe ("openssl.exe s_client -connect servername:8080") for more diagnostic info. You didn't mention but a proxy or an SSL-level certificate authentication could also cause problems, should be easily debuggable by the methods I mentioned above.

Comment: Wouldn't SSL issues affect other programs?  If I drop back to HTTP alone, I get "TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server..."; I'll poke around and see if I can find anything on this side.